# drupal installation error in www folder(apache)

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-7, ubuntu-10.04

ohk i am facing this very weird problem .

i have a cloud server hosted with rackspace and have installed ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx LTS in it. i have installed apache 2 , php and mysql server in it along with phpmyadmin.
when i download and extract drupal 7 default or any custom profiles i face this problem. When i extract it using tar -xzvf it extracts by default into /var/www/drupal-7.12/ and set permissions to 777 using chmod

not as you know that for website name to redirect to a ip address i should have index file in www folder instead of a sub folder so i copy all the files into www folder.

the problem is the drupal install page(in case of installation profiles) or index.php works in case of drupal default installation when they are in the subfolder(drupal-7.12) but when i copy all the installation files into the www folder the file index.php or install.php dont work and shows server error.

i tried many things to get it to work but no use.

need help . Thanks

Comment: So, you copied two files to a different directory, with no context, and you expect them to work?

Comment: it always worked in shared hosting .....and i copied all files of the installation and not just the index file obviously....isnt it cllear from the question......should i edit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out the problem myself. htaccess file wasnt copied. NOw as i have copied it everything works.